# Quartz SimpleTrigger not firing

Tags: java, triggers, cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm struggling with Quartz's triggers. I've created a service which is invoked through a cron expression but also it's a org.quartz.Job itself, the idea behind this is that once the service is invoked I check some variables and based on that I decide to delay (or not) the execution of the service for 1 day; for that, I get the `DefaultScheduler`, create a new `org.quartz.JobDetail` and a `org.quartz.SimpleTrigger`, and schedule them. As you may guess, it's not working, the new trigger is never started.

```
public class MyService implements MyInterface, org.quartz.Job {

    @Override
    //method declared in MyInterface
    public void generateFile() {
        org.quartz.Scheduler scheduler;
        try {
            scheduler = org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        } catch (SchedulerException e1) {
            scheduler = null;
        }
        if (condition) {
            //regular processing
        } else {
            try {  
                    org.quartz.JobDetail jobDetail;
                    SimpleTrigger simpleTrigger;
                    String name = "jobName";
                    if (scheduler != null && scheduler.isInStandbyMode()){
                        jobDetail = new org.quartz.JobDetail(name, org.quartz.Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP, MyService.class);  
                        jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("myService", this);                       
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int date = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
                        c.set(Calendar.DATE, date + 1);
                        simpleTrigger = new SimpleTrigger("simpleTrig", c.getTime());
                        simpleTrigger.setJobName(name);

                        jobDetail.setDurability(true);
                        scheduler.addJob(jobDetail, true);

                        scheduler.scheduleJob(simpleTrigger);
                        //also tested with 
                        //scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, simpleTrigger);
                        //and same result
                        scheduler.start();
                    }
                    else{
                        scheduler.shutdown();
                    }
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {  
                } 
                catch (org.quartz.SchedulerException ex) {  
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        MyInterface jobParamLogService = (MyInterface)jobContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get("myService");
        jobParamLogService.generateFile();
    }
```

As i said, my problem is that the `SimpleTrigger` never gets invoked (off course, I've tested adding a few minutes, not a day), does any have any tip about what's going on? 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: First thing you should do is handle your exceptions correctly. You may not adding the job to the scheduler because of a problem. Either log the message/stack trace or something is really important

Comment: Hi @ChrisHinshaw, thanks for your comment, the code I've show you is just a simplified version, I'm handling the exceptions, but none is thrown

Comment: 2 things here: 1) Why on earth do you lookup your service instance in such a complex way, while could just invoke `this.generateFile()` directly (omitting `this.` is just the same thing) 2) Why do you use a static call to default scheduler while you can access the actual scheduler directly from the JobExecutionContext provided to your job? My guess is that your condition is actually false  or that you access the wrong scheduler and eventually nothing happens indeed.

Comment: Hi @GuillaumePolet, thanks for your comment. Regarding the first question, probably you're right, I didn't realize that I could call `generateFile()`, I've followed an example without thinking... and regarding your second observation, I didn't know about the JobExecutionContext, but I think that's not the problem, actually when I get the scheduler it's the right one, it contains the job, and the trigger

Comment: Why do you test `isInStandByMode()`? This is most likely going to be always false since you are within a running job. Remove that check first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GuillaumePolet suggested, I've tried removing the `isInStandByMode` condition, but still didn't work. The trick was to replace the constructor with arguments for the default one (empty), and set the variables through the setter methods.
Thank you all for your help, kind regards

Comment: Old posts but I will still try; do you mean you did resolve this by `simpleTrigger = new SimpleTrigger()` and then using setters? I am having kind of same problem, I cannot get delayed trigger to start correctly - it either starts immediately or not at all.. :/

Comment: Hi @Jokkeri, it's a very old post and I don't even remember why I was trying to do that, but according to my comment, it seems that the problem was the constructor with arguments

Comment: Actually I finally figured out my problem... It was quite complex scenario where the actual problem was in naming of the jobs and some concurrency in them... The delayed start request was removed after ~1s in my code and thus never fired - my own bad =)